# Obligatory options for tcp syn

Tags: networking, tcp

I'm writing a soft for a microchip that will send some data via Ethernet and I've encountered a problem. I'm sending a TCP SYN segment and I have no answer from the server.

Everything looks fine, the only one difference between packets that gain answer and my ones is that my packets have no options (the pool described as optional). Are there some options that should be defined for SYN to work properly?

(If anyone know how to copy a packet from wireshark in a nice form I'll show you my packet.)

Comment: Can you provide the various header values for the SYN packet you're trying to send? Specifically, can you provide the value of your data offset and verify that your checksum is correct?

Comment: You're talking about tcp checksum or ip header checksum? Validation of tcp checksum is off and IP checksum is correct.

Comment: Are you generating this packet from scratch? If so, an error in any of the headers could cause the packet to be dropped. Have you successfully built a ping packet? This would verify your lower level headers (Ethernet, IP) are correct.

Comment: Yes, I'm building it from scratch, I'll try build ping packet, but what you understand as ping packet? This ICMP send by ping?

Comment: ping works properly, I've send echo reqest and got a reply

Comment: Is the TCP timestamp option necessary?

Comment: You can just save the TCP SYN that works and the one that doesn't as a K12 file and put that into your answer. We can import that into wireshark and have a look. - Regarding your comments: AFAIK, you cannot disable TCP checksum. Better calculate a proper one. And timestamp is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks a lot you're right. It'll be useless if it'll be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As cxxl mentioned in a comment the problem was incorrect TCP checksum.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your tcp header padding bytes are set to all 0's or 0xff